# Radio and checkbox HTML inputs displaying incorrectly in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have the following code that creates an input type of radio (jsfiddle for those who need it https://jsfiddle.net/dz3cq47x/1/):

```
<input class="classValue" type="radio" name="nameValue" value="1" checked>
```

Of course I have multiple of these.

The problem (WHICH IS ONLY IN IE10) I am having is they are displaying as you can see in the image below.

If I click them they work properly (as in displaying the correct information).

For some reason though they are not displaying properly as you see in the image below, and the one that's checked is not displayed as checked (they both have a period? in the select radio).

This is also happening with an input type checkbox.

```
<input class="classValue" type="checkbox" name="nameValue" value="monthly">
```

Any help is much appreciated in finding the reason as to why they are styled incorrectly in IE10.

Thank you very much,
Al

[image: Input type radio]

Comment: Could you provide a working example in a jsfiddle? Or at least the CSS that you're using to style these radios?

Comment: @TimMcClure Yeah definitely here is the link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dz3cq47x/

Comment: I'm not seeing anything resembling your image above, just default browser styles for radio inputs. I'm guessing that there is some CSS styling that is missing from your jsfiddle - can you make sure that you are not leaving anything out? e.g. what is making the radio buttons grey and tall?

Comment: @TimMcClure I updated it with all of the styling even the outside div styling for them https://jsfiddle.net/dz3cq47x/1/ they are not grey and tall except in IE10...in Chrome and IE11 they are big circles as shown in the code now.

Comment: @TimMcClure I should add the fact that I am testing in IE10 through the internet explorer emulation tab within the F12 Developer Tools

Answer (score 0):

I've solved as following:

```css
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]{
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
```